# facet serach results not showing the correct facet.field value

Tags: solr, facet

I am trying to do a facet search on the following field:

```
<field name="productTaxonomyName" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

the result for the facet search `select?q=gold&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=gold&facet.field=productTaxonomyName` were:

```
facet_fields":{
  "productTaxonomyName":[
    "set",2018,
    "necklac",1937,
    "ear",1761,
    "ring",750,
    "pendant",524,
    "bracelet",348,
    "anklet",112,
```

The field values should be `necklace sets, necklaces, earrings, mangalsutras, rings, pendants, bracelets and anklets` instead of what is showing up in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing these facet results because of the `fieldType` for your productTaxonomyName field. The `fieldType=text_en` settting is applying filtering, stemming, tokenization, etc. to the current field. You should store facet data with a `fieldType=string` in addition to the one you are currently using and then facet against this new field.

```
<field name="productTaxonomyName" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productTaxonomyName_facet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
```

Then you can use a copyField directive to populate the new field:

```
 <copyField src="productTaxonomyName" dest="productTaxonomyName_facet" />
```

Update your query to the following:

```
select?q=gold&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true
  &facet.query=gold&facet.field=productTaxonomyName_facet
```

For more details on this see the Facet Indexing section of [Solr Faceting Overview](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview).